# passing parameters in (click)="fun(param)" in ionic-angular2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having button in login.html file.

```
<button  data-sql="SELECT ep.PROJECTID,ep.PROJECTNAME FROM euser eu,eproject 
ep WHERE eu.projectid = ep.projectid AND eu.username = :USERNAME" 
data-sqlparams="USERNAME" data-logintype="otp" ng-click="customLogin()"> 

Login   

</button>
```

And Here my doubt is, Can i pass data-sql,data-params and data-logintype to login.ts file thru ng-click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to do but this should work:

```
<button #buttonElement data-sql="SELECT ep.PROJECTID,ep.PROJECTNAME FROM euser eu,eproject ep WHERE eu.projectid = ep.projectid AND eu.username = :USERNAME" data-sqlparams="USERNAME" data-logintype="otp" (click)="customLogin(buttonElement)">
```

Add #buttonElement to the button an then pass buttonElement as a parameter in the function, you have to use (click) instead of ng-click.

In the login.ts file:

```
public customLogin(data){
    let dataSql = data.getAttribute('data-sql');
    let dataSqlParams = data.getAttribute('data-sqlparams');
    let dataLoginType = data.getAttribute('data-logintype');
}
```